# My test is not detecting list elements - Protractor

Tags: javascript, protractor

I have following HTML:

```
<ul class="chosen-results">
<li class="active-result result-selected highlighted" data-option-array-index="0" style="">All Jobs</li>
<li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="1" style="">My Jobs</li>
<li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="2" style="">Passed Jobs</li>
<li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="3" style="">Failed Jobs</li>
</ul>
```

I am using following code to return each list element, but when the test is run, it doesn't detect any of those elements.

```
static get allJobs(){
       return element(By.className('data-option-array-index="0"'));
   }

   static get myJobs(){
       return element(By.className('data-option-array-index="1"'));
   }

   static get passedJobs(){
       return element(By.className('data-option-array-index="2"'));
   }

   static get failedJobs(){
       return element(By.className('data-option-array-index="3"'));
   }
```

Can someone tell if I'm returning the elements correctly.

Comment: These elements have their `class` set to `active-result`. That's what you would use as parameter for `By.className()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those aren't classes. You would need to use

```
By.css('[data-option-array-index="0"]')
By.css('[data-option-array-index="1"]')
By.css('[data-option-array-index="2"]')
By.css('[data-option-array-index="3"]')
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes as Dan Crews says it is not the class name it is an attribute inside the element. In addition to that if you want more specific than giving the array index.
The below would be the good solution

```
By.cssContainingText('All Jobs')
By.cssContainingText('My Jobs')
By.cssContainingText('Passed Jobs')
By.cssContainingText('Failed Jobs')
```

The above locator/selector are protractor specific too. And finds the element exactly even though there are hidden elements with the same class/attributes.

Since it finds with the unique name which is enabled and visible to the User.

And for finding which element is selected currently you can go with the class name like the below.

```
return $('.active-result.result-selected.highlighted')
```

If it really satisfy your question kindly up vote or choose as correct answer. If you need more details kindly comment.